# How to concatenate a pandas multi index column dataframe with a single index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, aggregation

I have the following piece of code where I'm trying to perform a group by aggregation on a pivot table and concatenate the resulting aggregation back into the pivot table dataframe. But I'm having issues joining tables of different levels.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
        ["alice", "school 1", "math", 95],
        ["alice", "school 1", "science", 87],
        ["charlie", "school 1", "math", 72],
        ["charlie", "school 1", "science", 63],
        ["bob", "school 2", "math", 92],
        ["bob", "school 2", "science", 68],
        ["dale", "school 2", "math", 56],
        ["dale", "school 2", "science", 78],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =["student_name", "school", "class", "class score"])

pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["class"], columns=["school", "student_name"])
print(pvt)
print()

aggregate_sum = pvt.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()
print(aggregate_sum)
```

**Pivot Table Output:**

```
             class score
school          school 1         school 2
student_name       alice charlie      bob dale
class
math                  95      72       92   56
science               87      63       68   78
```

**Aggregate Output:**

```
school   school 1  school 2
class
math          167       148
science       150       146
```

How do I concatenate the aggregate output into the pivot table on the same level as the student names?

**Expected Output:**

```
             class score
school          school 1                   school 2
student_name       alice charlie  sum      bob dale  sum
class
math                  95      72  167      92   56   148
science               87      63  150      68   78   176
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge with `merge` and update the multi-column name, and then create the multi-column with `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples()` to update the merged multi-column.

```
final = pvt.merge(aggregate_sum, on='class', how='inner')
final = final.rename(columns={'school 1':('class score','school 1','sum'), 'school 2':('class score','school 2','sum')})
cols = final.columns
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
final.columns = index
final = (final[[('class score','school 1','alice'),('class score', 'school 1', 'charlie'),
                ('class score','school 1','sum'),('class score', 'school 2','bob'),
                ('class score', 'school 2','dale'),('class score', 'school 2','sum')]])
final
        class score
        school 1    school 2
alice   charlie sum bob dale    sum
class                       
math    95  72  167 92  56  148
science 87  63  150 68  78  146
```